# Implement password caching

Tags: python, terminal, mechanize

I wrote a python script that lets users log in into a website by entering username and password and submit content using terminal. I am using `mechanize` to accomplish this. The problem is that users have to enter username and password every time they run the script. I want some way to cache the password for some time so that user doesn't have to enter password everytime and they get logged in for some time after they enter they enter username and password once. How can I do this?

Comment: why don't you just write the credentials to a file. then you can just check whether there is a file with credentials when you run your script and if so, use those instead of taking credentials as input

Comment: @SamG-H I want to keep the user logged in only for a certain amount of time after they enter their credentials. After which I want them to enter their credentials again. Writing it into file would log them in without them entering their credentials everytime they run the script.

Comment: You could write a timestamp to the file and check whether they are running the script within a certain timeframe, and if not, delete the file and require fresh input

Comment: @SamG-H Great! That could do it. But since the script is open source how can I make it secure?

Comment: I don't know of any particularly secure way to do this, because no matter what your program needs a plain text version of the username and password so you either have to store it in plain text or in a way that you can decrypt it (and therefore so can everyone else)